# Custom URL Scheme from settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, settings.bundle

Is it possible to set a custom URL scheme to launch my app from a link but make this a user defined setting?

My app relies on a user defined server url and I would like to be able to set a URL scheme to launch my app using the users custom URL from lets say an email link.

I noticed the info.plist has these references 
${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
can I define my own custom reference maybe?

Edit: Turns out these ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} are just references used during build in xcode.

I also learned that the app bundle is read only on device making the info.plist un-editable.
Looks like this is impossible. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add a link to a Settings.bundle to launch your app.